# resizing an image within ruby to fit within a DIV

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have an image that needs to be within the banner, but because i'm using a html.erb file i have to load the image with ruby so how do i go about resizing the image so it fits. the image needs to fit within the `<div id="banner"></div>` area, i'm not sure how to resize an image to do that though

the html and ruby for the code:

```
<div id='home_header'>
<div id='banner'><%= image_tag("banner.png", :alt=> "banner")%></div>
</div>
```

the css for the code:

```
#home_header {
background-color: #20C0CF;
position: absolute;
z-index: 0;
width: 98%;
height: 10%;
left: 0%;
top:0%;
border-bottom-style: ridge;
border-color: #0099FF;
border-bottom-right-radius: 100px;
}
#banner{
background-color: #FFFFFF;
position: absolute;
width: 30%;
height: 90%;
}
```

Comment: Your question is unclear. What do you mean by "within Ruby"? ERB doesn't "load the image," it just generates HTML. If this is a problem you'd ordinarily solve in HTML and CSS, you'll solve it Rails by writing ERB that generates that HTML and writing the same CSS. What, specifically, are you having difficulty with?

Comment: its alright ive already sorted it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by directly passing size attribute in rails `image_tag`.

```
<div id='banner'><%= image_tag "banner.png", :alt=> "banner", :size => '100X100'%></div>
```

It might distorted your image dimension. You can also pass only height for that particular `image_tag` and width will managed automatically by `image_tag`.

```
<div id='banner'><%= image_tag "banner.png", :alt=> "banner", :height => '100px' %></div>
```

In your banner due add css to align image in center.

```
#banner{ text-align: centre; }
```

Comment: so i cant use css for that? at all?

Comment: You don't need to do. I think this will solve your issue. If you want you can add some black area using background back in banner div. So it all look good for all dimension image.

Comment: its just the header is dependant on screensize and so if the image is a fixed size it will go over the edge on some screens

Comment: No it wont. As per my experience. 100px will calculate on basis of mobile screen, When you use mobile devise. Or use 100% in height element. That will fix the your concern.